Render only child template in ember js
I have an Ember.js application, and I have a route called parent/child. When I render the parent/child template, I only want the content inside the parent/child template to be displayed. I don't want the contents from the parent template to be rendered. How can I achieve this?
I tried using display:none and display:block on the current route, but it doesn't seem to be the correct approach. How can I prevent the parent template from being loaded at all?

Are you sure it should be a child route in this case? Why doesn't display:none seem correct?

Because, even if we do display none, it will still exist in DOM, and it can affect the performance of the site.

If you want the parent content to be hidden when you navigate to the child, you'll want to utilize the implicit parent/index.hbs route (don't add this to app/router.js (that creates index/index routes)).
For example
Before
parent.hbs
<h2>hi</h2>

{{outlet}}

After
parent.hbs
{{outlet}}

parent/index.hbs
<h2>hi</h2>

